# Congruence class to show that $[a]_8 \neq [b]_8$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $f : \mathbb{Z}_8 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$ be defined by $f([m]_8)=([m]_2,[m]_4)$ for $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ (assuming that $f$ is well defined). Find integers $a$ and $b$ such that $f([a]_8) = f([b]_8)$, but $[a]_8 \neq [b]_8$

In order to show that $[a]_8 \neq [b]_8$ it suffices to show that $a \neq b$ mod $8$

Perhaps I am misunderstanding, but is this question simply just asking to find (as one example)

$ 30 \not\equiv 7$ mod $8$ where $a = 30, $and $b$ = 7

Comment: We just started yesterday on congruence classes, so I apologize if this is a really basic question

Comment: Sure, $[30]_8\neq [7]_8$. But then again (assuming your definition of $f$ is what I _think_ it is, rather than what you say it is), $$f([30]_8) = ([0]_2, [2]_4)\neq ([1]_2, [3]_4) = f([7]_8)$$so it's not quite what the problem is asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about $a=0$ and $b=4$? For these numbers, $f([a]_8)=f([b]_8)=(0,0)$ but $[a]_8=0\ne4=[b]_8$.

Comment: Thank you! I guess it was the $f([a]_8)=f([b]_8)$ that was throwing me off. Very little to no reference in our textbook as to what that notation actually means.

Comment: @Forextrader The question is equivalently asking you to show that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: @Forextrader They might not have explained what $f([a]_8)=f([b]_8)$ means explicitly, but I guess they have explained the $[a]_8$ part. The $f(\phantom a) = f(\phantom a)$ part is probably something they expect you to be able to read already.